# Mysql Extract substring

Tags: mysql, database

I want to extract 
Sub Status: Broken Product and Sub-Sub Status: Body from such data.
Please help here. I tried using

```
substring_index(substring_index(comment, '<br >Sub Status', -1),
                       '|', 1)
```

but it did not help.

Item with IMEI OVRCT21012017-316 was marked Initiate Reverse Pickup against order number BST1100126008 due to following reason

> { Ticket # 70848... Concern: sends the images of the product - damage
>   and not working properly... Info: initiating a RPU...  }.
> Sub
>   Status: Broken Product | Sub-Sub Status: Body

.

Comment: From the description given, it's not clear, ath least not me, what you are actually trying to achieve. Are you trying to extract a substring out of a larger string? If yes, what is the format of the former and what of the latter? Can you also provide some examples with input and output string?

Comment: Your source string always have same structure?  I mean there is always `|` character after `Sub Status:` value and `Sub-Sub Status:` value always at the end of string?

Comment: Yes there is always | character after Sub Status: value and Sub-Sub Status: value always at the end of string.And there may be case when neither of two are present.In that case i want to get null.